# Passing string variable to an href with jQuery and JavaScript from form element

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, href

I am attempting to use the following bit of JS and jQuery to pass a variable (user's Email address form tfa_27) through an href link on the form.

I can redirect to the page, but the url just reads 'tfa_5?=$VARIABLE' instead populating the Email address into the URL, which ends my login state for the user. I know I am missing something ...

```
 function dynamicLinks(linkClass, fieldId) {

   var selection = $("#" + fieldId); 

   console.log(selection.val()); //Gives 'some.email@domain.ca'

   var linkArr = [];

   $(selection).each(function() { linkArr.push($(this).val()); });

   $(linkClass).attr("href", function(i, origLink) { return origLink.replace(/\$VARIABLE/, linkArr[i]); });
   //$(linkClass).attr("href", function(i, origLink) { return "https://tfaforms/XXXXXXX?tfa_5=" + selection.val() }); //Does not update href on form

  };


  dynamicLinks(".linkClass","tfa_27");
```

On the page itself, this is what my HTML href looks like this with the form ID hidden from SE for security reasons - the $VARIABLE should be an email address.

```
<a href="https://tfaforms.com/xxxxxxx?tfa_5=$VARIABLE">Back to Options</a>
```

Please note this piece of code is partially legacy code, so I may have some extra pieces - if so, please let me know! I am unsure how to move the variable into the href on the form, or how to build that href dynamically - I was told this would work well, but am missing something.
Thanks!

Comment: Notice, that the max value for the length of `selection` is 1, `id`s are supposed to be unique within the document. Very early jQuery versions selected multiple `id`s, though.

Comment: If that anchor element is actually what's in your document verbatim, it's not going to be found by the selector `$('.linkClass')` because that class isn't applied to the anchor element.  You might need something like `$('.linkClass').find('a')` if that class is on a parent.